# Vogel Sprichwörter/Doppeldeutigkeiten/Synonyme

Tags: idiom, synonym

Für ein Geschenk suche ich Sprichwörter/Doppeldeutigkeiten/Synonyme mit/über Vogelnamen, solche die im entferntesten damit zu tun haben oder auch einfach nur das Wort Vogel enthalten. Ich bin mir nicht sicher ob Sprichwörter/Doppeldeutigkeiten/Synonyme überhaupt die richtigen Begriffe sind, um zu erklären was ich meine (korrigiert mich bitte). Daher folgt jetzt eine Liste mit Sachen die mir bisher eingefallen sind, in keiner bestimmten Reihenfolge:

- Kuckkuck (im Sinne von "Guck guck"/als Begrüßung)
- Adlerauge
- Spatz (Kosenamen)
- etwas ausbrüten (z.B. eine Krankheit)
- Schnapsdrossel
- Nachteule
- im Sturzflug sein
- Geier (gieriger Mensch)
- Schwalbe
- Blumenstrauß (weit her geholt)
- taube Nuss
- Spaßvogel
- Pechvogel
- ein Hühnchen rupfen
- "Bei dir piepts wohl"
- Eine Meise haben
- Den Spatz in der Hand
- erdrosseln
- sich drosseln (im Sinne von "einen Gang runter schalten")
- Spatzenhirn
- Gänsehaut
- Hühnerauge
- Krähenfüße
- Star (im Sinne von "heute bist du der Star")
- Weiß der Geier
- Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm
- einen zwitschern (Alkohol trinken)
- vögeln (im Anschluss ans Zwitschern vielleicht)
- federführend sein
- einen Abflug machen
- Schnepfe
- den Vogel abschießen
- komischer Kauz
- geflügelte Worte

Viele Dank schon mal für eure Ideen.

Comment: Das könnte weiß der Geier eine lange Liste werden. Aber - zum Kuckuck! - warum werden Aufrufe zum Sammeln hübscher Beispiele aus der Welt der lebenden Sprache immer gleich mit "close" zur Schnepfe gemacht?!

Comment: Frage allerdings: "taube Nuss" kann sich ja hier eigentlich nur als Kuckucksei eingenistet haben, oder?

Comment: Ihr habt ja allen 'nen Vogel...

Comment: Sollten wir aus dieser Listen-Frage nicht eine [Community-Wiki-Frage](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/was-ist-eine-community-wiki-frage) machen, damit jeder einzelne Sprichwörter beitragen kann ohne dass diese Liste in viele verschiedene Antworten zerteilt wird?

Comment: @Devon    Das böte sich wohl an...

Comment: @Devon muss ich dafür was machen?

Comment: [Der frühe Wurm hat einen Vogel](https://amalthea.at/produkt/der-fruehe-wurm-hat-einen-vogel/) (Buch von Michael Niavarani)

Comment: @Hubert   Eine andere bekanne Variation ist: *Der frühe Vogel kann mich mal*.

Comment: +1 für die Frage. Ich verstehe nicht, wieso sie unter dem Aspekt „proofreading, spell checking or translations of individual texts“ oder „off topic - too broad“ geschlossen werden sollte.

Comment: Ich verstehe schon, dass es im eigentlichen Sinne keine Frage ist. Einerseits weil ich sie tatsächlich nicht als Frage formuliert habe und anderseits (wahrscheinlich der triftigere Grund) weil sie nicht eine richtige Antwort haben kann. Welche der (wirklich guten) Artworten sollte ich als DIE Antwort akzeptieren?

Comment: @Thomas.  Ich sehe es so: Die Frage ist: *Welche Wendungen und Wörter sind im Deutschen gebräuchlich, die sich mit Vögeln oder mit ihren linguistischen Repräsentationen inhaltlich oder formal in Verbindung bringen lassen, ohne direkt Vögel zu meinen?* Die Antwort ist dann eine (möglichst vollständige) Liste solcher Ausdrücke. - Das Problem, dass mehrere Antworten "richtig" sein können, hast du bei anderen Fragen auch. Du sollst ja auch nicht sagen, welche "richtig" ist, sondern welche dir am meisten geholfen hat.

Comment: Sie ist zu breit gefächert (too broad) – was explizit *nicht* außerhalb des Seitenthemas (off topic) ist – weil sie nach einer sehr ausführlichen Liste frägt, die niemals wirklich vollständig werden kann. Es gibt eben nicht zwei, drei oder fünf sondern extrem viele potenzielle Antworten. Damit ist diese Frage das Lehrbuchbeispiel einer zu breit gefächerten Frage.

Comment: @Jan   Die Frage, ob Fragen, die keine abschließende Antwort haben können, unzulässig sind, mal dahingestellt: Im konkreten Fall möchte ich die These wagen, dass die Liste mit vogelbezüglichen Wendungen im Deutschen letztlich doch (so gut wie) eine endliche sein wird. Wir haben schon sehr viele Ausdrücke beisammen, und man merkt, es wird nun schwer und schwerer, weitere zu finden. Prognose: Bei ca. 200 wird's dann wirklich eng. Wäre das nicht dann doch eine (fast) vollständige Antwort?

Answer (score 6):

- jemandem den roten Hahn aufs Dach setzen (alt für: das Haus anzünden)
- mir schwant nichts Gutes
- sich einnisten in etwas
- jemandem ein Kuckucksei ins Nest legen
- an etwas herumnesteln
- sich aufschwingen
- dumme Gans
- hässliches Entlein
- Nachtigall, ick hör dir trappsen!
- Eulen nach Athen tragen
- sich (zu etwas) mausern
- (ein) Nesthäkchen (sein)
- Nestwärme suchen
- flügge werden
- Eieiei! (Ausruf)
- Gänsemarsch
- Wackelente
- sich aufplustern
- herumschnäbeln
- reihern (sich übergeben)
- (für jemanden) schwärmen
- Federn lassen
- flatterhaft sein
- vogelfrei
- frei wie ein Vogel
- eitler Pfau
- Flügeladjutant
- herumstaksen
- den Kopf in den Sand stecken
- Da brat mir einer einen Storch!
- Eine Schwalbe macht noch keinen Frühling.
- sich etwas herauspicken
- blindes Huhn (findet auch ein Korn)
- früher Vogel (fängt den Wurm)
- beim ersten Hahnenschrei
- da kräht kein Hahn nach
- rumgackern
- kiebitzen (speziell beim Kartenspiel jemandem über die Schulter schauen)
- spechten (gezielt wo hineinschauen)
- eierlegende Wollmilchsau
- Schwalbenschwanz (der Schmetterling!)
- Spätzle (süddeutsche Mehlspeise, siehe auch Spätzlesschwob)
- Vogelhochzeit halten
- Wasserhahn
- "Ente gut, alles gut!" (Sprichwort)
- Entente cordiale (Hist.)

Comment: *»An etwas herumnesteln«* hat aber nichts mit einem Nest, und daher auch nichts mit Vögeln zu tun. Das Wort *nesteln* ist mit *Netz* verwandt. Die *Nestel* war eine Kopfbinde, auch Schnürriemen wurden als Nesteln bezeichnet. Das Verb *nesteln* bedeutete früher *zubinden, schnüren*.

Comment: @Hubert   Ah! Danke für diese Aufklärung! - Allerdings fühle ich mich auch mit "nesteln" hier noch in sicherem Gehege, denn auch der Eingangsfragesteller listet ja Beispiele auf, die nur wortformal mit Vögeln zu tun haben, wie *Blumenstrauß* und *taube Nuß*.

Comment: Ähm, was hat denn die Entente cordiale hier zu suchen? Entente heißt Übereinkunft und hat nichts mit irgendeinem Vogel zu tun.

Comment: @RHa. Ein berechtigter Einwand. Aber was hat der *Blumenstrauß* (siehe Eingangsfrage) mit dem Vogel Strauß zu tun? Auch nichts. Es ist aber die gleiche Wortform. Und da wir bei Enten waren... in Entente sehe ich mindestens eine.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann Gut, als Wortspiel kann man es viel gutem Willen vielleicht durchgehen lassen.

Comment: @Ja, mei... *Ente gut, alles gut*, ist ja auch bloß ein Wortspiel... und Flügeladjutant ist vielleicht kein Wortspiel, aber doch schon sehr weit hergeholt (es geht ja nicht unbedingt um solche Flügel bei ihm).

Answer (score 5):

- ein schräger Vogel
- die Rauchfangtaube (wienerisch: ungepflegte Person meist weiblichen Geschlechts)
- warten dass einem die gebratenen Tauben in den Mund fliegen
- einen Strauß ausfechten (Strauß = Konflikt)
- (lieber den) Spatz in der Hand (als die) Taube auf dem Dach
- eine Lerche sein (Gegenteil von (Nacht)Eule)
- a Lercherlschaas (wienerisch: eine Kleinigkeit)
- Storchenbiss (roter Hautfleck)

Comment: Frage mich gerade, ob die wienerische Rauchfangtaube mit der Bordsteinschwalbe verwandt ist :)

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Eher nicht. Die Bordsteinschwalbe geht auf den Straßenstrich, bemüht sich also, einen gewissen sexuellen Reiz auszustrahlen. Die Rauchfangtaube nicht. Die Rauchfangtaube ist schmutzig, trägt schäbige Klamotten und stinkt.

Answer (score 3):

Mir fallen da noch die *Hühnerbrust*, das *faule Ei*, den *Schnabel halten*, *jemanden einen Vogel zeigen*, *reihern* (kotzen), *rabenschwarz*, der *Schwanenhals*, der *Schwanengesang*, der *Storch im Salat*, der *Flattermann* (Durchfall), der *Gänsewein* (Wasser) und die *Ente* (Auto) ein. Lohengrins *mein lieber Schwan* ist auch sehr gebräuchlich. Außerdem gibt es noch die *Rabeneltern*, welche in der Regel aus einem *Rabenvater* und einer *Rabenmutter* bestehen.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn's abwegig werden soll:

**Am sel**ben Tag **fink** es zu regnen an. Das Fe**storch**ester spielte so lange, bis der Ordinariu**s patz**te und sich in üb**elster** Manier vergeigte. O**b ihr d**as jetzt mögt, sei dahingestellt.

Comment: Wenn schon denn schon!

Comment: Mach doch bitte hier keine Fisimat**enten**.

Comment: **Ent**lich sagt mal einer **gäns**lich die Wahrheit!